# Creating a Facebook comment box for different sites

Tags: facebook

I want to add the facebook comment box to several websites for different people. IT asks for an Appid which at first I thought meant their Facebook Business page id. Now im realizing that I need to create a Facebook App for this. My question is this, can I create one app, take the ID and use that for several different comment boxes on various sites that are not related and owned by different clients? Or should I make new Apps for each one?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment boxes are separated by the URL you define in the HTML attributes, so technically you can use the same App ID for multiple clients since the pages have different URLs.

Still - I would advise you to create a new application for each client. At some point one client might ask you to give them admin access to the Facebook application - and you don't want to give one client access to the application that also serves your other clients...